# Unable to load view error in codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

Controller:

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() 
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if(!is_logged_in()){
            redirect('admin');
        }
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('templates\sub_header');      
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
        $this->load->view('templates\footer');
    }
}
```

when called controller should simply load three views in sequence. Instead I keep getting error "Unable to load the requested file: templates\sub_header.php".

Important point to note is that this code is working perfectly fine on localhost but giving issues on godaddy subdomain.

I have defined a base url in the config file which seems to work fine.

On other hand another controller is working just fine everywhere:

```
public function index()
    {
        if( is_logged_in() )
        {
            redirect('welcome');
        }

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="text-danger">', '</div>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'UserName', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[4]');
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('auth/login_view');
        }
        else
        {
            // Check the entered value against db
            $this->load->model('auth/admin_model');
            $result = $this
                    ->admin_model
                    ->verify_user($this->input->post('username'),$this->input->post('password'));

            if($result != false)
            {

                $username = $this->input->post('username');
                $status = $result->status;

                if($status == 1)
                {
                    $user_roles = $this->admin_model->get_user_access_roles($result->id);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('username', $username);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('user-management',$user_roles->user_management);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('client-information',$user_roles->client_information);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('master-metadata',$user_roles->master_metadata);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('reports',$user_roles->reports);
                    redirect('welcome');
                }
                else 
                {
                    $data['error_message'] = "Account is disabled. Get in touch with system administrator !";
                    $this->load->view('auth/login_view',$data);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $data['error_message'] = "Invalid UserName or Password. Try Again !";
                $this->load->view('auth/login_view',$data);
            }
        }
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

Views are loaded perfectly in Admin controller but after login when admin controller redirects to welcome controller, views stop loading. Only difference between the controllers is that in Admin controller i am calling header while in welcome i am calling sub_header but both file are present inside views folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `\` to this `/`

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('templates/sub_header');    # Changed   
    $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer'); # Changed 
}
```

and ***make sure Files are exist***

Comment: This was a silly mistake but can you help me understand that why it was not throwing error in localhost but only on remote server.

Comment: Probably you are using windows server. So no harm. but if Linux server it's an issue,

Comment: @Saurabh Hapy to help  :)